# How to pass the value into the view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I writed a plugin that start from the file,
I want to pass the file context into a view,
Anybody can tell me how to pass the context into the view?

Comment: Your view shows information about a file which is selected in another view? Did I get that right? Is it an eclipse view, the `Package Explorer` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you pass the objects between editors using 'EditorInput'. Create a POJO class extending EditorInput and then pass it as a parameter when you opening a new editor:

```
protected void openSingleObjectEditor(final IEditorInput input,final String editorID){
        IWorkbenchPage page;
        page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
                .getActivePage();
        try {
            page.openEditor(input, editorID);
        } catch (PartInitException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```